# Connecting internet to Raspbery Pi board

Tags: linux, networking, embedded

I have successfully ported Linux kernel to Raspberry Pi board.
But now i need to have Internet connection into it.
And my internet connection is like, it needs a user name and password to login then only we can access Internet(wired internet through LAN or RJ 45 connector). And this interface for entering username and password comes in a browser.

But now in case of Raspberry pi , its just a kernel so , i do not have a browser in it.
So how to connect this internet connection in Board.

Thanks

Comment: Your question look a bit off-topic. However you can simply write a script (in your language of choice) to simulate a user who logs in using a browser.

Comment: The problem is , in raspberry pi , i have ported just the linux kernel. it does not have a browser..
So how i need to enter the username and password ,, is there any provision to do it in browser

Comment: I just told it to you.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, your answer is right, but now i have to figure it out how to simulate a browser using script...

Comment: Kind of funny that you "ported" linux to a board which was never designed to run anything else.  You'll probably need to "port" wget as well, and play with it's user & password options.  Note that if you have "just the linux kernel" you do not have a usable system - about the minimum you can do is to run a primitive shell as your init.

Answer (score 1):

The hardware solution is to use a home router that does the logging-in for you, and then acts as a gateway between your local LAN and the Internet. You would connect the Raspberry Pi to one of the router's LAN ports, and use either DHCP or static IPs on that local net.

A software solution might be using e.g. curl to implement some kind of login-script that fakes the accesses to the web page.

Answer (score 0):

If you could connect it (temporarily) to an Internet connection that doesn't require a login/password, you could install a command line based browser. I would suggest looking into Lynx, if you choose to do it this way. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29

Comment: Ya ,i also have thought of using a command line browser . i have tried w3m and elinks till now, it shows error on opening that webpage ,, else every other page is gettng opened.. i will try lunkx now,, thanks for reply